# Closing at the right time and waiting process in C

Tags: c, process, pipe

I have a function which create two child process. In the first child process I am writing in a file and in the second one I am also writing in a file which is different from the first one.
In the dad process I am executing the function `execvp`.

What I need is the `stdout` and `stderr`of the function `execvp`, so that the two child process can write in files what goes out from `stderr` and `stdout`. Then at the end I am merging the two files.

I would like to know where I should close pipes and where I should use wait so that I don't have problem using function `read` and `write` and such that I don't go in a infinite loop. I didn't implement the functions that create files, the function that merge files and the function that run the shell instruction because I am just wondering if this is the best structure for the function `createTwoChild.`

Comment: You need something like e.g. `popen()` if you want to read output from a child.

Comment: @reichhart Thank you, but I am not trying to read output from a child. The child are just writing in files. Do you think the overall structure is good ? I am not sure about how I close pipes

Comment: It's not clear if you simply want to merge the outputs of the childs into the output of the father. Reg. "time": sighandler is missing for SIGCHLD. (Unfortunately the edit timeout happened when editing my comment.)

Comment: @reichhart Thank you. The two Childs are creating two files and they write in this files. Then I merge this two files.

Comment: @reichart Hmmm you are right I should put two wait(NULL) right ?

Comment: Yes, wait() is missing. But reg `by reading file descriptor stdout[0]`: I don't see `stdout[0]` fd assignment after `pipe()`.

Comment: @reichhart Actually wait will not work since execvp is going to kill my dad process. I am doing dup2(stdout[1], 1) in the dad process. Thus everything that enters in stdout[1] will go out to stdout[0]

Comment: Means: stdout of parent is "shared" to both childs? And: What should be done with `stderr[]`? Try to provide only the required code (maybe w/o stderr) but with full logic required like e.g. fd assignements.

Comment: Another question: Do you actually need the files written "to disk"?

Comment: What might be also misleading here are the names of the pipes with `stdout`and `stderr`. Better use something like e.g. `pipe_child1`, `pipe_child2`.

Comment: @reichhart stdout is shared with the first child and stderr is shared with the second child (using pipes as show in the code). First child copy what goes out from stdout[0] in a file and second copies what goes out from stderr[0] in a file. And yes these two files are created on the disk with the function open.

Comment: Well, to me it looks very different: You don't need two childs. Please correct if I'm wrong. You do an `exec()`. But this you need to do as a child. And then in the master simply handle stdout and stderr of the exec'ed child. Couldn't it be like that? (And by doing it that way you even don't need to catch also SIGPIPE.)

Comment: @reichhart Hmmm yes I didn't think about that. Thank you. Can you provide just the structure just to see if it works. The problem is that how to you connect the stdout of the child with one of the parent and where to wait then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aligned on the comments I'm providing a skeleton here (simplified just for stdout):

```
if (pipe(fd)<0) goto my_sys_error; // just an example to get out of here
if ((pid_child=fork())<0) {
  close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]);
  goto my_sys_error; // you can also use something like e.g. "return -1" to handle the error
}

if (!pid_child) {
  // the child process with exec() of which we want to get the output
  close(fd[0]); close(0);
  dup2(fd[1],1); close(fd[1]); 
  execXX(...); // some of exec() family also spawn a shell here
  close(1);
  _exit(127); // This must not happen
}

// master/parent
close(fd[1]); // master doesn't need, only child writes to it
i = read(fd[0],p,PIPEBUF_SIZE);
if (i>0) { 
  // usual handling, write to file, do whatever you like
  // should be while() instead of if(), just simplified
} else {
  // handle it, e.g. print "no data from extcmd"
}   
close(fd[0]); // close the last fd
waitpid(pid_child, &status_child, 0); 
if (!WIFEXITED(status_child)) {
  kill(pid_child,SIGKILL);
}
```

Some notes:

- This is actually a simplified implementation of `popen()`.
- When the child exited then you will get an EOF on read - in this simple way no sighandler for SIGCHLD is required.
- Other signal handling not covered.
- stderr can be simply added with an additional pipe.

Comment: Thank you ! Here you are executing the shell instruction in the master process not in the child one right ?

Comment: It's just a snippet and shows a basic solution. I don't know where your "shell" comes in. But the master/parent is handling the output from exec'ed child. You can even do more voodoo here by forking another child to read the data asynchronously if the master needs to do additional things and must not be blocked by its exec'ed child. Or create a thread (e.g. `clone()`) for async handling. (Added comments about sys_error.)

Comment: "Accepted" looks like you don't have any questions left, do you? BTW - if you are able to upvote the accepted solution then please do this also.